# Angular.js: how to update one item of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, node.js

Background: app built in Angular (with routing), Node, Express, MongoDB/Mongoose.

In one controller I have an array of stuff `$scope.array=[];` whose items are fetched through an `$http` request.

I have a routine which modifies one item of the array:

```
$http.get('/api/update?id='+itemId, ..
```

Upon success of the `get` request, I have to update the specific item of `$scope.array` which has been modified. I know a possible way is to re-fetch the complete array, but seems inefficient.

Can anyone suggest a way to update/substitute only the item which has been modified?

Comment: **Note**: Probably one way would be something like `$scope.array[array.indexOf(modifiedItem)]=updatedItem`
but as far as I know `indexOf` does not work in IE browsers.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something simple like this. You probably already know this.

$scope.array.splice(this.$index,1, updatedItem);

This will replace/update item in array at $index position if you already looping on array with Id check.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a strategy like below;

```
var modified_item_index = arrayIndexOfModifiedItem;
$http.get('').onSuccess(function(result){
    $scope.dataArray[modified_item_index] = result;
});
```

Essentially use a closure scoped variable to store the array index of the modified item.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a library with your web app (e.g., jQuery) then you can use their IE7/8 support (e.g., jQuery's `$.inArray`).  If not, you can include a simple "polyfill" for IE7/8:

`if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj, start) {
         for (var i = (start || 0), j = this.length; i < j; i++) {
             if (this[i] === obj) { return i; }
         }
         return -1;
    }
}`

See [How to fix Array indexOf() in JavaScript for Internet Explorer browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/how-to-fix-array-indexof-in-javascript-for-internet-explorer-browsers) for more on this.