# Why javascript indexOf "empty string" always returning zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexof

Why javascript indexOf method always return 0 for empty string. If i used any string indexOf("") always returns zero. Any reason for this. Explain the reason briefley.

```
var str="jquery";
var index=str.indexOf("") \\ Always returns zero for any string.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: because it will find empty string at the very starting of the search string so everytime it will return index 0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/how-to-fix-array-indexof-in-javascript-for-internet-explorer-browsers