# indexOf empty string is zero. why?

Tags: javascript, indexof

why this is happening in javascript?

```
'abc'.indexOf('a');        //0
'abc'.indexOf('');         //0
```

while in the other falsy values, the value is -1:

```
'abc'.indexOf();           //-1
'abc'.indexOf(false);      //-1
'abc'.indexOf(undefined);  //-1
```

i have seen also those questions: 
[Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28692565/why-javascript-indexof-empty-string-always-returning-zero) didnt understand the answer in depth.
[Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683466/java-string-indexof-and-empty-strings) in java and not javascript.

Comment: `"false".indexOf(false)` is 0.

Comment: And `"undefined".indexOf()` is also 0.

Comment: While the duplicate is about the Java programming language, the answer applies to this question.

Comment: @nbokmans this is javascript

Comment: @NguyễnThanhTú Yes. And the answer applies here because it's about strings, not the language used.

Comment: Well, by standard, 4th step of `indexOf` implementation is calling `toString` on first argument. So it looks for `"undefined"` string in given string. More [here](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.prototype.indexof)

Comment: The answer (for JavaScript and for Java) is basically: Because that's how the function is specified to behave. For JavaScript, [details here](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-string.prototype.indexof). Fundamentally, if the start position (0 in your example) plus the length of the search string (0) isn't greater than the length of the string you call it on (0), it loops checking code units. Since there are no code units to check, and 0 + 0 isn't greater than 0, the result is 0.

Comment: Is it a really good idea to like that question as duplicate to one of a different language? I mean the fundamental idea might be the same, but it would not be the first time that the reason why (the specs) for that behavior are different for another language. I mean Java and JavaScript could use two different approaches to handle/specify this.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder fixed.

Comment: @t.niese - Yeah, I'm not convinced either. [It's been done before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28692565/why-javascript-indexof-empty-string-always-returning-zero), too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer, fundamentally, is: Because that's how the function [is specified to behave](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-string.prototype.indexof). And it makes sense, from a certain perspective.

The main bit related to returning 0 when you search for an empty string is this:

> Return the smallest possible integer *k* not smaller than *start* such that *k + searchLen* is not greater than *len*, and for all nonnegative integers *j* less than *searchLen*, the code unit at index *k + j* within *S* is the same as the code unit at index *j* within *searchStr*; but if there is no such integer *k*, return the value -1.

Since the length of the search string is 0, both halves of that "and" are satisfied by *k = 0*: `k + searchLen` is not greater than the length of the string, and for all nonnegative integers less than the search length (there are zero), the code points match.

Or roughly speaking, in code:

```
function indexOf(searchString, position = 0) {
    let s = String(this);
    let searchStr = String(searchString);
    let len = s.length;
    let start = Math.min(Math.max(position, 0), len);
    let searchLen = searchStr.length;
    let k = 0;
    while (k + searchLen <= len) {
        if (s.substring(k, k + searchLen) === searchStr) {
            break;
        }
        ++k;
    }
    const found = k + searchLen <= len;
    return found ? k : -1;
}
```

Since `k + searchLen` (0) is `<=` `len` (0), `k` (0)` is returned.

Live Example:

```js
function indexOf(searchString, position = 0) {
    let s = String(this);
    let searchStr = String(searchString);
    let len = s.length;
    let start = Math.min(Math.max(position, 0), len);
    let searchLen = searchStr.length;
    let k = 0;
    while (k + searchLen <= len) {
        if (s.substring(k, k + searchLen) === searchStr) {
            break;
        }
        ++k;
    }
    const found = k + searchLen <= len;
    return found ? k : -1;
}

console.log(indexOf.call("abcd", ""));
```

Another way to look at it is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2683509/157247) related to Java...or to life in general.

---

Re your question passing in non-strings: One of the first steps is:

> Let *searchStr* be ? ToString(*searchString*).

...which is `let searchStr = String(searchString);` in my rough code above. That means `false` becomes `"false"` and `undefined` becomes `"undefined"`. `"abc"` doesn't contain either `"false"` or `"undefined"`.

Comment: @ofir_aghai - Fixed.