# javascript findIndex issue with IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I've just completed a small form and found out that how I'm using findIndex doesn't work with IE.

Here is an example of the issue.

```
var people = [
  {name:"Mike", age:"25"},
  {name:"Bill", age:"35"},
  {name:"Terry", age:"44"}
];
console.log(people.findIndex(x => x.name=="Bill" ));
```

What would be the fastest way to fix this issue for IE?

Comment: Have you seen [How to fix Array indexOf() in JavaScript for Internet Explorer browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/how-to-fix-array-indexof-in-javascript-for-internet-explorer-browsers)?

Comment: Use a polyfill, such as the one [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex).

Comment: ^^ + IE11 doesn't support ES6 arrow functions.

Answer (score 2):

find index support for browsers

```
    Chrome 45.0 and above: Supports

    Firefox 25.0 and above: Supports

    Internet Explorer: No support

    Microsoft Edge: Supports

    Opera: Supports

    Safari 7.1 and above: Supports
```

So you need to modify your code something similar to below to work in all browsers.

```
var index;
for(var i=0;i<people.length;i++){
  if(people[i].name == 'billi'){
   index = i
 }
}
```

[More info](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/03/findIndex-issue-in-IE.html)

Answer (score -3):

this is best for IE

```
people.findIndex(function(x){ x.name=="Bill" }));
```

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: because I tested it and I had the same problem

Comment: findIndex method isn't supported by IE11, you have to use polyfill instead if you want that functionality.