# How to collect only unique values in an Array in Internet Explorer 11 by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer

from many articles I have chosen this syntax to make unique values in an array.

```
pairs = pre_final_pairs.filter((elem, index) =>  pre_final_pairs.indexOf(elem) === index).join(' ');
```

This works perfectly in all browsers except Internet Explorer 11.

I have tried to find which of the command from the line is not compatible and I found that maybe the **indexOf**. But even if I tried to apply "fix" referred in [How to fix Array indexOf() in JavaScript for Internet Explorer browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/how-to-fix-array-indexof-in-javascript-for-internet-explorer-browsers) still the page is not working in the IE11.

Also I have loaded https://code.google.com/archive/p/ddr-ecma5/ library in order to ensure that the ECMA commands will work.

And still getting [SCRIPT1002: Syntax error](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=CS-CZ&k=k(VS.WebClient.Help.SCRIPT1002))

Do you see there a wrong part in the command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internet Explorer [does support `indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Browser_compatibility), but [does not support arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility).

You can easily fix that using a regular function for the callback instead:

```
pairs = pre_final_pairs.filter(
    function (elem, index) {
        return pre_final_pairs.indexOf(elem) === index;
    }
).join(' ');
```